# jQuery $(this) not working with class:nth-of-type()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having an issue with jQuery where when selecting an element with `nth-of-type()` within the bound function, it will not allow me to access it with `$(this)`

```
$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)").on('click', (e) => {
  alert("CLICKED PANEL 2");
  $(this).css({
    background: "red"
  });
});
```

The above will run the `alert()` but the `$(this)` does not get hit and throws no errors. If I change the `$(this)` to `$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)")` it will then work without any issues.

Comment: `$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)", this)` is the same as `$(this).find(".panel:nth-of-type(2)")`, so it all depends on what `this` refers to when that code runs.

Comment: @Pointy My bad, that is not what I'm actually trying to run... updated the question.

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(this)` to see what its value is?  jQuery will *definitely* set it to some element when it invokes the handler. *edit* — well it'll try at least :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an arrow function. These have no access to `this`. Arrow functions use lexical scoping.

You have 2 options. Either convert the function to a normal one, or use `e.currentTarget` instead of `this`

```js
$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)").on('click', function (e) {
  alert("CLICKED PANEL 2");
  $(this).css({
    background: "red"
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Using `e.currentTarget`

```js
$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)").on('click', (e) => {
      alert("CLICKED PANEL 2");
      $(e.currentTarget).css({
        background: "red"
      });
    });
```

```css
.panel {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Comment: Wow man, you were first!!! Great!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have got the similar situation, and it's better not to use the `=>` fat arrow function for this, assuming it changes the context of `this`. Use a regular function:

```
$(".panel:nth-of-type(2)").on('click', function (e) {
  alert("CLICKED PANEL 2");
  $(this).css({
    background: "red"
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also use an arrow function and rather than `this` use `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @CarlMarkham Yes, saw your answer. Thanks!  That was useful.